# How do I use a python dictionary to create a csv file?

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have consulted the official documentation and even with a few tests, I do not know how to create a csv file from a list. I looked at [this post about lists and csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6413636/writing-csv-file-from-a-list-in-python) as well as [this post about dictionaries and csv.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6740918/creating-a-dictionary-from-a-csv-file) I honestly don't understand the function of the quotechar, I guess, well here is my example.

```
import csv

test = [["Number 1", "Number 2"], [1,0], [0,1]]


with open('nums.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    writer.writerows(test)
```

I simply need to know how to make the CSV file from this style of list. So that Number 1 &  Number 2 are in the same row but in two different columns. And so that the numbers are seperated as well, currently it just puts the pair of numbers in the same field and goes to the next row.

Comment: Have you opened the csv file and checked? It works as expected.

Comment: Are you opening the CSV file using a non-US Excel version? In many European countries, Excel expects `;` as a delimiter, not `,`. (Also, what you have there is not a dictionary, so you might want to rename your question)

Comment: Well I have opened it up on libre calc, and it appeared as described which is why I posted it. How should I open it?

Comment: Well, does it work when you use `delimiter=';'`?

Comment: @TimPietzcker The title originally included both because I was not sure which data structure would be most useful. I am using libre calc, US.

Comment: @TimPietzcker when I use 'code'(delimiter=';') it does work with libre! Though why do the spaces create a new field in the row as well?

Comment: I don't know LibreCalc, but I would expect it to handle CSV files correctly. This is strange. It seems that the issue is not with Python but with LibreCalc, then - you might want to ask your question at their support page.

Comment: Actually, my question has been answered thank you! I simply needed to know that in the common dialect it was properly formatted so I could us pandas on it.